# TypeError: e.getPosition is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm trying to update my lat and lng after a marker is dragged. and update input's with id's `lat` and `lng`. but i'm getting some errors

Here is my code

```
function createMyLocationMarker(point) {
       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: EGMap0,
              position: point,
              draggable:true,
              title:"Hello World!"
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(e) {
            jQuery("#lat").val(e.getPosition().lat());
            jQuery("#lng").val(e.getPosition().lng());
        });
}
```

I get this error

```
TypeError: getPosition is not a function on
jQuery("#lat").val(e.getPosition().lat());
```

also tried this

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(event) {
            document.getElementById("#lat").value = event.getPosition().lat();
            document.getElementById("#lng").value = event.getPosition().lng();
        });
```

but get this error

```
    TypeError: event.getPosition is not a function
document.getElementById("#lat").value = event.getPosition().lat();
```

any idea what i'm missing here? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(event) {
          var lng= event.latLng.lng();
          var lat= event.latLng.lat();
        });
```

or use this.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(e) {
            document.getElementById("#lat").value = event.latLng.lng();
            document.getElementById("#lng").value = event.latLng.lat();
        });
```

Im using JS here